# Chrome V49 & V50 Console Panel Autofill / Auto-Suggestion

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome V49 and V50 change the way that the "autofill" function works in the console panel.

- In Chrome V48, if you type in a letter, the autofill frame will pop up and provide suggestions of the built-in variables/functions that start with the input letters;
- In Chrome V49 & V50, however, the autofill frame also provides options of previous user inputs (as illustrated in the link below). If you have typed in something wrong, the autofill frame will still keep it as a suggestion for always, while I cannot find a way to clear the history of user inputs.

[Autofill in Chrome Canary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGaVV.png)

I am wondering if I have missed something - Is there a way to prevent the autofill in the console panel from automatically remembering the user input and keep them as suggestions? Or is there a way to manually clear the history of user inputs? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A setting for this does not exist currently. You can file a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://crbug.com/new) to see if it is something the team wants to add in.

Comment: I have reported this issue to them. Thanks for your advice!